# Which classifiers work well with unbalanced data?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

I have a binary classification problem which is very unbalanced - it can have 98% of data from one class.  Which classifiers work well with this sort of data?

I have an unlimited supply of training data, since I produce it using a pseudo random number generator.  However, I found that to get a neural network to produce decent results, I had to generate balanced (50:50) data.  This is the equivalent of over-sampling.  The problem with this approach is that the training data is then not representative of real life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options:

- Do not use accuracy alone as a metric. That way, we would get 98% accuracy with everything classified as the majority class, which would not mean anything. [Precision & Recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) might be a better one.
- You could try using a [Cost sensitive classifier](http://weka.wikispaces.com/CostSensitiveClassifier) through which you can state the cost of misclassification of the different classes.
- Use an SVM but penalize one of the classes which can be done using [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f410)
- boost the number of minority class training examples by artificially creating new samples from the existing samples.
- resample the set, to have a proportional number of samples in both the classes (probably not an option in your case)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to @[tdc](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7365/tdc)'s reply: the problem with skewed data is that models tend to over-fit and result in biased models. For some of them there are modifications to the original formulation that help correcting that bias. For example, there are alternative formulations of [naive Bayes](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/FrankAndBouckaertPKDD06new.pdf), [kNN](http://rp-www.cs.usyd.edu.au/~weiliu/Webpage/kNN_pakdd11.pdf) which deal with this problem.

As he points out: the problem is that usually one attempts to maximize the accuracy. And that makes the classifier "focus" on the most populous classes, since that yields better accuracy.